# How to extract text with indentation from a pdf?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdfminer

I want to extract text from a pdf paper. However when I extract with the code below the returned text is something like:

```
section text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text
```

But I want the section to come with the normal indentation:

```
                 Section
text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text
```

Follows the sample:

```
import io

from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

def extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, 
                                      caching=True,
                                      check_extractable=True):
            resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
            fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
            converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
            page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)

            text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
            yield text

            # close open handles
            converter.close()
            fake_file_handle.close()

def extract_text(pdf_path):
    for page in extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
        print(page)
        print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(extract_text('w9.pdf'))
```

Is it possible to do this with pdfminer?

Answer (score 0):

The `TextConverter` is intended to convert the pdf to plain text, without considering the position of elements. The reason behind this is that it is difficult to render the text positions in a pdf accurately using plain text, even when using monospace fonts.

The `HtmlConverter` and `XMLConverter` output a file that contains both the text and the positioning of the text. Perhaps you can use this output to create the result that you want.

If your needs are more specific you could also consider to write your own `PDFConverter`. This gives you control over everything including beginning and ending of pages, rendering images, drawing polygon paths and writing text to specific positions.